# Missing Sybase ASE ODBC Driver in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sap-ase

I'm a ASP .Net developer and I have this application that queries from a Sybase 12 database in a database server.
Previously, I had Sybase 12 Open Client in my Win XP machine and I had the **Sybase ASE ODBC Driver** listed in the ODBC Admin screen.
My connection string is something like this: "**Driver={SYBASE ASE ODBC Driver};Database=mydb;NA=something;uid=something...**"

However, a few weeks ago, our machines were upgraded to Win7.
I found out that I have Sybsae 15 Open client in my machine now and I can't find the Sybase ASE ODBC Driver in the ODBC Admin screen, so it must not be installed.
When I asked the people here responsible for the Win7 upgrade, they said that the Sybase 12 driver is no longger compatible with Win7.

How am I supposed to continue working on the application I'm developing? Is there a Sybase ASE ODBC Driver for Win7 that I need installed? I just need something that will allow my code to connect to the same Sybase 12 database as it had been doing before.

Answer (score 0):

That only comes with [ASE](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/adaptiveserverenterprise).